# How to verify Microsoft SQL Server Product Key is Original?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2012, sql-server-2008-r2, sql-server-2014

I am using Microsoft SQL Server 2016 in my office, SQL Server Key license has been given to me from operational Department,how can i verify that the product Key is Original Key or crack key founded from internet.

Is there any official website of Microsoft or any other company weather i can check SQL Server product key.

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe there is a verification service for MS keys. The operational department of your company should be able to answer any queries on the origin of the keys.

Ideally, if you are not responsible for the software purchase and licensing, you should not have any problems using the key supplied.

Comment: off course it is not my responsibility for software purchasing but this is not correct answers,at least i have to be confirm that software is original.
this also not your responsibility to show my responsibility to me.

Comment: I am not showing you your responsibility, but if you want to know the authenticity of the keys you use,the only two places that can verify that are your company's operation department or contacting Microsoft Support who will be able to direct the query to the right department. As I already mentioned there is no online service as it would violate customer data protection for them to tell you who the key belongs to without validating your identity.

Comment: "at least i have to be confirm that software is original." no. if you get it from operations, you are in the clear. Period. THEY have to provide the paperwork of purchase if microsoft comes asking. All you are at this point is - sorry - a troublemaker.